# How to bind Dynamic variable in JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

How should I bind the Id i am getting in a variable **@item.ArticleId** to a JavaScript code which gets the id dynamically?

My use case is that I have to show the **Comment TextBox** at the click on the **Add A Comment Button**.

Following is the code on how I am getting the Article ID:

```
<span id="addComment" onclick="AddaComment()"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Add a Comment</span>

            <div id="Comment(@item.ArticleId)" style="display:none;">

                <input type="hidden" name="ArticleId" id="ArticleId" />
                <input type="text" name="Comments" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn add-comment" value="Add Comment">
            </div>
```

Below is my code for JavaScript:

```
function AddaComment() {
        var x = document.getElementById("Comment()");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
function AddaComment(id) {
        var x = document.getElementById("Comment_"+id);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```